# In R how to divide a row when a condition is met

Tags: r, dataframe, factors

I have a bunch of means associated with unique values. The unique values are lines that I tested on two different substrates. in R I want to build a loop that will take the unique value and divide the means (pheno_output) of substrate A by substrate B. and spit this into a new vector.

This is what I am working on.

```
tmpmeans<-  rep(NA, 2);

for (i in unique(SplitnonMEANs$Line)){
  tmpmeans<- SplitnonMEANs$pheno_output[i]/SplitnonMEANs$pheno_output[i]
}
```

example data:

```
s;

Line phenotype FoodSource pheno_output
1    non        A           123
2    non        A           456
1    non        B           789
2    non        B           159
```

Can anyone help me do this?

Comment: I don't follow.  Do you want the mean by group? Like the result from `aggregate(pheno_output ~ FoodSource, df, mean)`

Comment: I have the means, I want to divide by pheno_output by foodSource. SO take unique 1 and divide A/B, take unique 2 and divide A/B

Comment: well in this case it would be two, because I have two unique values based on s$Line. Sorry about that

Comment: Please supply us the two numbers you expect as the result

Comment: This works great, can you explain this? Sorry

Comment: Richard, what happened to the answer you gave? It worked perfect. I was asking how your piece of code worked?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was wrong `sapply(split(df$pheno_output, df$Line), function(x) x[1]/x[2])` Also, `aggregate(pheno_output ~ Line, df, function(x) x[1]/x[2])` gives a nicer result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have two values per group, you can use any of these

```
divide <- function(x) {
    stopifnot(length(x) == 2L)
    x[1L]/x[2L]
} 
aggregate(pheno_output ~ Line, df, divide)
#   Line pheno_output
# 1    1    0.1558935
# 2    2    2.8679245
with(df, tapply(pheno_output, Line, divide))
#         1         2 
# 0.1558935 2.8679245 
sapply(split(df$pheno_output, df$Line), divide)
#         1         2 
# 0.1558935 2.8679245
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table` would be faster

```
 library(data.table)
  setDT(df)[,list(pheno_output=ifelse(.N==2, pheno_output[1]/pheno_output[2], NA_real_)), by=Line]
  #  Line pheno_output
 #1:    1 0.1558935
 # 2:   2 2.8679245
```